# Excluding bibliography from mini ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies

I am using this book [template](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/books/the-legrand-orange-book) for my work. Straight to the question: how to exclude bibliography (and appendix, index, etc) from the mini ToC? It should still appear in the main ToC.

Comment: The link to the ShareLaTeX stuff works, but you have errors in that file that prevents compilation. The usual way is however to provide code here and not somewhere else.

Comment: It's relatively long code, I don't know how to shorten it. And I encountered no errors during compilation.

Comment: The compilation stops due to errors in structure.tex. There is a nested (!!!!) `tikzpicture` environment. Which mini ToC do you mean at all? The bookmarks of the `.pdf` file or the 'mini ToC' of the part pages?

Comment: I don't understand, the code works fine here. FYI, I am an absolute beginner in Latex. I can guarantee that my knowledge is a subset of yours.

Comment: I've obtained the linked code to my disk and corrected the error (Note: The Legrand Orange book template has some issues and I don't recommend its usage at all). But again: Which MiniToC do you mean? Your document does also show no appendix, but in your question you refer to it...

Comment: Look at mini ToC for the Part Two. You can see Bibliography at the bottom of the page. I don't want it to be there (it should appear in main ToC only). For the appendix and index, I mean in case if I add them later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert the `\stopcontents` command just before `\chapter*{Bibliography}`, this will prevent further entries to the local `ToC`, but does not omit them from the main `ToC`.

Information: The `\@part` command within `structure.tex` uses `\startcontents` for each part in order order to generate a local `ToC`.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% The Legrand Orange Book
% LaTeX Template
% Version 2.2 (30/3/17)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Original author:
% Mathias Legrand (legrand.mathias@gmail.com) with modifications by:
% Vel (vel@latextemplates.com)
%
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
% Compiling this template:
% This template uses biber for its bibliography and makeindex for its index.
% When you first open the template, compile it from the command line with the 
% commands below to make sure your LaTeX distribution is configured correctly:
%
% 1) pdflatex main
% 2) makeindex main.idx -s StyleInd.ist
% 3) biber main
% 4) pdflatex main x 2
%
% After this, when you wish to update the bibliography/index use the appropriate
% command above and make sure to compile with pdflatex several times 
% afterwards to propagate your changes to the document.
%
% This template also uses a number of packages which may need to be
% updated to the newest versions for the template to compile. It is strongly
% recommended you update your LaTeX distribution if you have any
% compilation errors.
%
% Important note:
% Chapter heading images should have a 2:1 width:height ratio,
% e.g. 920px width and 460px height.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book} % Default font size and left-justified equations

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\input{structure} % Insert the commands.tex file which contains the majority of the structure behind the template

\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begingroup
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[inner sep=0pt] (background) at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{background}};
\draw (current page.center) node [fill=ocre!30!white,fill opacity=0.6,text opacity=1,inner sep=1cm]{\Huge\centering\bfseries\sffamily\parbox[c][][t]{\paperwidth}{\centering The Search for a Title\\[15pt] % Book title
{\Large A Profound Subtitle}\\[20pt] % Subtitle
{\huge Dr. John Smith}}}; % Author name
\end{tikzpicture}
\vfill
\endgroup

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COPYRIGHT PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newpage
~\vfill
\thispagestyle{empty}

\noindent Copyright \copyright\ 2013 John Smith\\ % Copyright notice

\noindent \textsc{Published by Publisher}\\ % Publisher

\noindent \textsc{book-website.com}\\ % URL

\noindent Licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial 3.0 Unported License (the ``License''). You may not use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at \url{http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/3.0}. Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the License is distributed on an \textsc{``as is'' basis, without warranties or conditions of any kind}, either express or implied. See the License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under the License.\\ % License information

\noindent \textit{First printing, March 2013} % Printing/edition date

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TABLE OF CONTENTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%\usechapterimagefalse % If you don't want to include a chapter image, use this to toggle images off - it can be enabled later with \usechapterimagetrue

\chapterimage{chapter_head_1.pdf} % Table of contents heading image

\pagestyle{empty} % No headers

\tableofcontents % Print the table of contents itself

\cleardoublepage % Forces the first chapter to start on an odd page so it's on the right

\pagestyle{fancy} % Print headers again

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PART
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\part{Part One}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CHAPTER 1
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\chapterimage{chapter_head_2.pdf} % Chapter heading image

\chapter{Text Chapter}

\section{Paragraphs of Text}\index{Paragraphs of Text}

\lipsum[1-7] % Dummy text

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Citation}\index{Citation}

This statement requires citation \cite{book_key}; this one is more specific \cite[122]{article_key}.

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Lists}\index{Lists}

Lists are useful to present information in a concise and/or ordered way\footnote{Footnote example...}.

\subsection{Numbered List}\index{Lists!Numbered List}

\begin{enumerate}
\item The first item
\item The second item
\item The third item
\end{enumerate}

\subsection{Bullet Points}\index{Lists!Bullet Points}

\begin{itemize}
\item The first item
\item The second item
\item The third item
\end{itemize}

\subsection{Descriptions and Definitions}\index{Lists!Descriptions and Definitions}

\begin{description}
\item[Name] Description
\item[Word] Definition
\item[Comment] Elaboration
\end{description}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CHAPTER 2
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\chapter{In-text Elements}

\section{Theorems}\index{Theorems}

This is an example of theorems.

\subsection{Several equations}\index{Theorems!Several Equations}
This is a theorem consisting of several equations.

\begin{theorem}[Name of the theorem]
In $E=\mathbb{R}^n$ all norms are equivalent. It has the properties:
\begin{align}
& \big| ||\mathbf{x}|| - ||\mathbf{y}|| \big|\leq || \mathbf{x}- \mathbf{y}||\\
&  ||\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbf{x}_i||\leq \sum_{i=1}^n||\mathbf{x}_i||\quad\text{where $n$ is a finite integer}
\end{align}
\end{theorem}

\subsection{Single Line}\index{Theorems!Single Line}
This is a theorem consisting of just one line.

\begin{theorem}
A set $\mathcal{D}(G)$ in dense in $L^2(G)$, $|\cdot|_0$. 
\end{theorem}

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Definitions}\index{Definitions}

This is an example of a definition. A definition could be mathematical or it could define a concept.

\begin{definition}[Definition name]
Given a vector space $E$, a norm on $E$ is an application, denoted $||\cdot||$, $E$ in $\mathbb{R}^+=[0,+\infty[$ such that:
\begin{align}
& ||\mathbf{x}||=0\ \Rightarrow\ \mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}\\
& ||\lambda \mathbf{x}||=|\lambda|\cdot ||\mathbf{x}||\\
& ||\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y}||\leq ||\mathbf{x}||+||\mathbf{y}||
\end{align}
\end{definition}

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Notations}\index{Notations}

\begin{notation}
Given an open subset $G$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$, the set of functions $\varphi$ are:
\begin{enumerate}
\item Bounded support $G$;
\item Infinitely differentiable;
\end{enumerate}
a vector space is denoted by $\mathcal{D}(G)$. 
\end{notation}

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Remarks}\index{Remarks}

This is an example of a remark.

\begin{remark}
The concepts presented here are now in conventional employment in mathematics. Vector spaces are taken over the field $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$, however, established properties are easily extended to $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{C}$.
\end{remark}

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Corollaries}\index{Corollaries}

This is an example of a corollary.

\begin{corollary}[Corollary name]
The concepts presented here are now in conventional employment in mathematics. Vector spaces are taken over the field $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$, however, established properties are easily extended to $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{C}$.
\end{corollary}

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Propositions}\index{Propositions}

This is an example of propositions.

\subsection{Several equations}\index{Propositions!Several Equations}

\begin{proposition}[Proposition name]
It has the properties:
\begin{align}
& \big| ||\mathbf{x}|| - ||\mathbf{y}|| \big|\leq || \mathbf{x}- \mathbf{y}||\\
&  ||\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbf{x}_i||\leq \sum_{i=1}^n||\mathbf{x}_i||\quad\text{where $n$ is a finite integer}
\end{align}
\end{proposition}

\subsection{Single Line}\index{Propositions!Single Line}

\begin{proposition} 
Let $f,g\in L^2(G)$; if $\forall \varphi\in\mathcal{D}(G)$, $(f,\varphi)_0=(g,\varphi)_0$ then $f = g$. 
\end{proposition}

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Examples}\index{Examples}

This is an example of examples.

\subsection{Equation and Text}\index{Examples!Equation and Text}

\begin{example}
Let $G=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2:|x|<3\}$ and denoted by: $x^0=(1,1)$; consider the function:
\begin{equation}
f(x)=\left\{\begin{aligned} & \mathrm{e}^{|x|} & & \text{si $|x-x^0|\leq 1/2$}\\
& 0 & & \text{si $|x-x^0|> 1/2$}\end{aligned}\right.
\end{equation}
The function $f$ has bounded support, we can take $A=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2:|x-x^0|\leq 1/2+\epsilon\}$ for all $\epsilon\in\intoo{0}{5/2-\sqrt{2}}$.
\end{example}

\subsection{Paragraph of Text}\index{Examples!Paragraph of Text}

\begin{example}[Example name]
\lipsum[2]
\end{example}

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Exercises}\index{Exercises}

This is an example of an exercise.

\begin{exercise}
This is a good place to ask a question to test learning progress or further cement ideas into students' minds.
\end{exercise}

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Problems}\index{Problems}

\begin{problem}
What is the average airspeed velocity of an unladen swallow?
\end{problem}

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Vocabulary}\index{Vocabulary}

Define a word to improve a students' vocabulary.

\begin{vocabulary}[Word]
Definition of word.
\end{vocabulary}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PART
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\part{Part Two}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CHAPTER 3
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\chapterimage{chapter_head_1.pdf} % Chapter heading image

\chapter{Presenting Information}

\section{Table}\index{Table}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l l l}
\toprule
\textbf{Treatments} & \textbf{Response 1} & \textbf{Response 2}\\
\midrule
Treatment 1 & 0.0003262 & 0.562 \\
Treatment 2 & 0.0015681 & 0.910 \\
Treatment 3 & 0.0009271 & 0.296 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Table caption}
\end{table}

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Figure}\index{Figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{placeholder}
\caption{Figure caption}
\end{figure}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   BIBLIOGRAPHY
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\stopcontents
\chapter*{Bibliography}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textcolor{ocre}{Bibliography}}
\section*{Books}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Books}
\printbibliography[heading=bibempty,type=book]
\section*{Articles}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Articles}
\printbibliography[heading=bibempty,type=article]

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   INDEX
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.75cm}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textcolor{ocre}{Index}}
\printindex

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

[image]